# How do I use react-redux-toolkit query in my single-product react component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, redux-toolkit

Backend route:

```js
const express = require('express');

const productroute = express.Router();

const {getallproducts, getsingleproduct} = require('../controller/productscontroller')

productroute.get('/shop', getallproducts)

productroute.get('/shop/:id', getsingleproduct)

module.exports = productroute
```

Frontend RTK-Query:

```js
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from "@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react"

export const productApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: "productApi",
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({baseUrl: "http://localhost:5000"}),
  endpoints: ((builder)=> ({
    getAllProducts: builder.query({
      query: () => "/shop"
    }),
    getSingleProduct: builder.query({
      query: id => `/shop/${id}`
    })
  }))
})
```

app.js router links:

```
<Route path='/about' element={<About />} />
<Route path='/' element={<SharedProductLayout />}>  
  <Route path='/shop' element={<Shop />} />
  <Route path='/shop/:Id' element={<Prodparams />} /> 
</Route>
```

React component:

```
export const {
  useGetAllProductsQuery, 
  useGetSingleProductQuery
} = productApi;
```

```
const Prodparams = () => {
  const { data, isloading, error } = useGetSingleProductQuery()

  const { Id } = useParams()

  const product = data.find((product) => {
    return product.id === Id
  })

  const { _id, image, prodcat, heading, price, ratings, discription, AddCart, BuyCart } = product
  
  return (
    <div className="blog">  
      <Container>
        <Row>
          <Col md={6} id={_id} className="bg- ">
            <div className="img">
              <img src={image} className='img-fluid' alt="" />
            </div>
            {/* <Row className='bg- mt-4'>
            <Col md={4} className='bg-'>
              <img src={image} alt="" className='img-fluid' />
            </Col>
            <Col md={4} className='bg-'>
              <img src={image} alt="" className='img-fluid' />
            </Col>
            <Col md={4} className='bg-'>
              <img src={image} alt="" className='img-fluid' />
            </Col>
            </Row> */}
          </Col>

          <Col md={6} className="bg-">
            <div className="p-dist">   
              <p className='product-category'>{prodcat}</p>
              <h2 className='heading'>{heading}</h2>
              <small className='ratings text-center'>
                {ratings}
                <BsStarFill />
              </small>
              <h4 className='price'>{price}</h4>
              <p className='discription'>{discription}</p>
              <Link to=''>
                <button className='add-cart mx-2'>
                  {AddCart}
                </button>
              </Link>
              <Link to=''>
                <button className='buy-cart mx-2'>
                  {BuyCart}
                </button>
              </Link>
            </div>
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </Container>
    </div>
  )
}
 
export default Prodparams
```

Comment: I really would appreciate help on this one. I have fetched the product from the backend using RTK query but i keep getting single product undefined in my single product component. How do i use the id in Params is a confusing.

Comment: `Array.prototype.find` potentially returns undefined if no matches in the array are found. Can you [edit] the post to include an example of the fetched data the code is searching, and the router/routing code to see what path params are available? See [mcve].

Comment: I want to fetch my products from the backend using rtkquery.
I succeded in fetching all the products and it displayed well in the frontend so
i didnt include the code. 
When i try to click on individual products it says undefined.
My first code is the backend route.
My second code is the rtk section.
The third is the ruote section in my app.js file.
The fourth is my singlee-page react component.
What is making my single products to be undefined?
please bear with me, should have used code sandbox.

Comment: @tchrist Ah, no worries, stuff happens... I was just curious as to how the title was what was updated while so many formatting issues remained in the body.

Answer (score 0):

If the data has been correctly fetched but the specific details about a specific product by id are not found then there are a couple things to be aware of.

1. `Array.prototype.find` potentially returns `undefined` if no array element is matched via the predicate function. The UI should handle this case, usually by rendering `null` or some fallback UI.
2. Route path params are ***always*** a String type, so if the property used to match by in each array element is ***not*** a string, then using strict equality, e.g. `===`, will very likely not find a match, e.g `123 === "123"` is false. You should use a type-safe comparison. It's typical to convert the element property to a String, e.g. `String(123) === "123"`.

Example:

```
const Prodparams = () => {
  const { data, isloading, error } = useGetSingleProductQuery();

  const { Id } = useParams();

  const product = data.find((product) => String(product.id) === Id);

  if (!product) {
    return <div>No product details. Go back and try another product.</div>
  }

  const {
    _id,
    image,
    prodcat,
    heading,
    price,
    ratings,
    discription,
    AddCart,
    BuyCart
  } = product;

  return (
    <div className="blog">  
      ...
    </div>
  );
};
```